# ListView concurrency issue

Tags: asp.net

I am stuck up at a typical issue with ListView and concurrency. I have a ListView which I am binding in code behind (not using SQLDataSource).

1. I bind the ListView in Page_Load with a collection returned from database.
2. I handle "edit" command in "ItemEditing" event handler like this:

```vb
Me.MyListView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
BindMyListView();
Me.MyListView.InsertItem.Visible = False;
```

1. Other operations are handled the same way thru `ItemInserting`, `ItemUpdating`, `ItemDeleting`and so on.

When I browse the page, the ListView shows up fine. When I click "Edit" command link, then the ListView nicely gets into the editing mode. When I click "Save" command link, the record perfectly gets saved. All good.

The **problem** starts when, the ListView is loaded up on the page and some other user deletes a record just before I click "edit" on that record. The ListView gets into the edit mode, but on the next row. Same happens when deleting a record. If some other user deletes a record just before I click "Delete", the next record gets deleted.

After much mucking around, I could see that it is the "index" which is being used by the framework. So, if the record is already deleted, when the ListView binds again (on postback) the index would now point to the next record!

I am unable to work around this. I have tried using "CommandArgument" but it also returns the argument of the next row. When the ListView is bound during Page_Load, the edit index pointer is now at the next record and the "CommandArgument" contains the next row's argument.

Need help from you guys.

Thanks / @bhi

Here is the complete code, which works fine but with the above mentioned **problem** :

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        PrepareListView()
    End Sub

Private Sub BindMyListView()
    Dim items = BusinessLogic.GetData()
    Me.MyListView.DataSource = items
    Me.MyListView.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Sub MyListView_ItemCanceling(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCancelEventArgs) Handles MyListView.ItemCanceling
    e.Cancel = True
    Me.MyListView.EditIndex = -1
    BindMyListView()
    Me.MyListView.InsertItem.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub MyListView_ItemDeleting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles MyListView.ItemDeleting
    Dim autoId As Integer = 0
    autoId = Integer.Parse(Me.MyListView.DataKeys(e.ItemIndex).Value.ToString)
    BusinessLogic.Delete(autoId)
    BindMyListView()
End Sub

Private Sub MyListView_ItemEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewEditEventArgs) Handles MyListView.ItemEditing
    Me.MyListView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    BindMyListView()
    Me.MyListView.InsertItem.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub MyListView_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewInsertEventArgs) Handles MyListView.ItemInserting
    Dim item As DomainModel.DataObject = New DomainModel.DataObject 
    item.Id = 0
    item.DataValue = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("txtDataValue"), TextBox).Text
    BusinessLogic.Save(item)
    BindMyListView()
End Sub

Private Sub MyListView_ItemUpdating(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles MyListView.ItemUpdating
    Dim item As DomainModel.DataObject = New DomainModel.DataObject 
    item.Id = Integer.Parse(Me.MyListView.DataKeys(e.ItemIndex).Value.ToString)
    item.DataValue = DirectCast(Me.MyListView.Items(e.ItemIndex).FindControl("txtDataValue"), TextBox).Text
    BusinessLogic.Save(item)
    Me.MyListView.EditIndex = -1
    BindMyListView()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing you code it's difficult to say for sure, but based on your desciption you are binding the `ListView` in `Page_Load` every time.

You should change this so that you bind the `ListView` in page load only if it's not a post back:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindMyListView();
    }
}
```

My sample is in C#, but should hopefully be easy to translate to VB.